# Are there standard dimensions for probes?

Tags: probe, standard

I have a probe card with cantilever probes, from a manufacturer that no longer exists. I need to know the lengths and vertical angles of the probes, and ideally the lengths of the tips. Since probes are very fragile, I would like to avoid measuring them myself and certainly destroying the tip.

Are there any standard sizes for probes that I can reasonably assume apply to the ones I have?

Comment: I think you need a major edit on your question. (1) What is a probe card. (2) What is a cantilevered probe. (3) What is the name of the manufacturer - even if the company no longer exists. (4) What is the model or part number of the card. (5) Where is the photo? Please put all this information and anything else that might help **in your question** and not in the comments.

Comment: So hm, you have probes from a manufacturer you don't want to mention, and you don't know the size but also neglect to show a picture of the setup. I can't see how anyone could help you, even if they're experienced with this type of gear.

Comment: The answer to your title: No. Many probe cards are even still hand-assembled to custom order with a selection of pin types and lengths, depending on characteristic impedances and other parameters. So... See @transistor's comment if you want to have any chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probe-card probes are not standard. They are custom made for the particular probe-card vendor. Furthermore, they are custom-assembled and typically custom-potted into an epoxy ring to tightly control their position and alignment. So even if you could get individual probe wires, they are not replaceable on a probe-card.

There are SOME kinds of probe cards made with ceramic or metal "probes" that are soldered onto the card. That kind MAY be replacable, but proper positioning and alignment typically require very specialized equipment and skills.

For those who don't know, probe cards are used to contact dice on a wafer for testing of individual integrated circuits while they are still on the wafer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of a probe card. OP should have done that.